# DatePicker showing empty date vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datepicker, null

So, in VB.NET, I can see the current date ("Tuesday, April 18, 2017") however in run time, I get the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LshI1.png

Any idea on what could be going on? Just started to happen.

Comment: It appears that you have set the `Format` property to `Custom` and the `CustomFormat` property to an invalid specifier.  Have you and, if so, what is the format specifier?

Comment: Actually I don't. That's what is confusing me. I have the format property set to Long.  I even deleted the existing control and replaced it with no success.

Comment: Here's the IDE and run time side by side. http://i.imgur.com/dkRVtqw.png

Comment: We're having the same problem on a project, but it's only on one PC that apparently had the creator's update, maybe this is related? Also, it only happens on existing projects, new projects seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate the problem.

In the search for your operating system, type "date format" and click on the entry for "Change date and time formats". Verify that the entry for **Long date** is:

```
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
```

You might want to switch it to something else and then back again just to be sure the setting is saved.

Back in Visual Studio, add a new DateTimePicker to your form and call it dtpSample and then put this code in the form load event:

```
With dtpSample
    .Value = Now.AddMonths(1) '1 month in the future
    .ShowUpDown = False
    .Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long
End With
```

If when you run the project now and the date in dtpSample is fine and still wrong in the other one, then it sounds like you have something in your code is breaking/altering the original control.

Comment: I just created an additional DateTimePicker on the form and never referenced any bit of code to it, just dropped it into the form and had the exact same issue.

However, compiled it and launched it on another system and it works fine. Now, I got to figure out what's wrong in Windows...

Comment: @KyGrayson we have the same problem and we think it's the Creators Update but we're still testing to see if that holds true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Application built with VS2015 but it only appeared when deployed to a "Creator's Update" PC. Turned out that the "Enable application Framework" checkbox needed checking within the projects Application page, as per the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/upeYT.png

Comment: Just checked the project and it's checked. I do have the Creator's Update on this system, however, I've moved most of my development to a different system as I'm rebuilding this system from scratch. :-)